# Unresolved external tokens with template class

Tags: c++

**SOLVED: I was an idiot and included the header file at the bottom of the header file rather than the implementation file.**

This project is for an assignment in my C++ class so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I know template classes cause issues with compilers so you have to do special things to make them read it. My professor provided us with the 6 steps that 'fix' this. I followed all of them but I am still getting a bunch of unresolved token errors.

The errors I am getting:

LNK2028, LNK2019, LNK1120(Multiple of each)

Header File:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace cs_pairs
{
template <class T>
class orderedPair
{
public:
    static const int DEFAULT_VALUE;

    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;

    orderedPair(value_type newFirst = DEFAULT_VALUE, value_type newSecond = DEFAULT_VALUE);
    void setFirst(value_type newFirst);
    void setSecond(value_type newSecond);
    value_type getFirst();
    value_type getSecond();
    orderedPair operator+(const orderedPair& right);
    bool operator<(const orderedPair& right);
    void print();

    class DuplicateMemberError {};
private:
    value_type first;
    value_type second;
};

template <class T>
const int orderedPair<T>::DEFAULT_VALUE = int();

#include "orderedPair.h"
}
```

Implementation File:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "orderedPair.h"
using namespace std;

namespace cs_pairs
{
template <class T>
orderedPair<T>::orderedPair(value_type newFirst = DEFAULT_VALUE, value_type newSecond = DEFAULT_VALUE)
{
    setFirst(newFirst);
    setSecond(newSecond);
}

template <class T>
void orderedPair<T>::setFirst(value_type newFirst)
{
     if statement to throw an exception if precondition not met goes here.   
    if (first == second)
    {
        throw DuplicateMemberError e;
    }
    first = newFirst;
}

template <class T>
void orderedPair<T>::setSecond(value_type newSecond)
{
     if statement to throw an exception if precondition not met goes here.    
    if (first == second)
    {
        throw DuplicateMemberError e;
    }
    second = newSecond;
}

template <class T>
typename orderedPair<T>::value_type orderedPair<T>::getFirst()
{
    return first;
}

template <class T>
typename orderedPair<T>::value_type orderedPair<T>::getSecond()
{
    return second;
}

template <class T>
orderedPair<T> orderedPair<T>::operator+(const orderedPair<T>& right)
{
    return orderedPair(first + right.first, second + right.second);
}


template <class T>
bool orderedPair<T>::operator<(const orderedPair<T>& right)
{
    return first + second < right.first + right.second;
}


template <class T>
void orderedPair<T>::print()
{
    cout << "(" << first << ", " << second << ")";
}
}
```

Comment: Why do template classes cause issues with compilers?  I haven't had any issues with the template classes I've written.

Comment: In order for a compiler to *read* a template class, you have to *instantiate* the template with the parameters.  A good example is `std::vector`.

Comment: What is `orderedPair.h`? You probably don't want to be including it inside the `namespace cs_pairs`. You also need to have the implementation file included inside the header file, because you need a full definition of the template class for any instantiation.

Comment: Please **edit your post** with the compiler errors **verbatim**.  No links, no pictures or images, text only.

Comment: Are you really using a compiler that gives you such cryptic error messages as "LNK2028"? Well, you can still attack it the old-fashioned way. Try removing code (e.g. commenting out function definitions) a little at a time, and watching the number of error messages dwindle. Try to make the code as simple as you can, while still producing at least one of the errors. Look at the last little piece of code, whose removal silences the last error message; it has a bug in it. (I see six or seven things that look like bugs, but it's hard to be certain since you haven't really told us the whole story.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove '#include orderedPair.h' from your header. You don't want any header file to include itself.

You may have though about including lan implementation file which, in that case, would be correct.